# Countifs with 3 criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have all CRM data pushing into a google sheet and I am trying to see granular data like the number of leads a specific employee works month to month. I need to look at 3 separate criteria in order to do so. The three critera are: (stage, assignee, month). I am able to return aggregate leads using the following:

```
 =countifs('Data feed'!$AE$2:$AE$1674,C1,'Data feed'!$B$2:$B$1674,"proposal sent - Active") + countifs('Data feed'!$AE$2:$AE$1674,C1,'Data feed'!$B$2:$B$1674,"Verbal Yes")
```

```
'Data feed'!$AE$2:$AE$1674 = date column
C1 = Date of Month
Data feed'!$B$2:$B$1674 = Stage Column
"proposal sent - Active" = Stage
```

and I am able to look at monthly revenue by person with:

```
=sumifs('Data feed'!$H$2:$H$1674,'Data feed'!$AK$2:$AK$1674,C$1,'Data feed'!$R$2:$R$1674,"*maconachy*")
```

How do I look at leads by person?

Comment: Did you try to add the 3rd criterion? I'm confused what your question actually is.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Here is a simplified copy of what I am working with. The two green cells are the expected outcome if I could make the formula work. The two yellow rows on the dashboard tab are the rows I am trying to populate. The blue rows and columns on both tabs are the parameters I am trying to reference or pull in. The light red row is an example of the kpi I am going for without the third parameter added in (the third parameter being the person it is assigned to).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19iNBMzbVJCpWs3qHjzNy4hzhV5xv0QpLHIyxl5T7ZME/edit?usp=sharing